# What is my mistake in this determinant of order $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, determinant

Consider real numbers $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and the following determinant

$$ \alpha_n= \begin{vmatrix} a_1 + b_1 & b_1 & b_1 & b_1&\cdots & b_1 \\  
b_2 & a_2 + b_2 & b_2 & b_2 & \cdots & b_2 \\
 b_3 &   b_3 & a_3 + b_3 & b_3 & \cdots & b_3 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_n & b_n & b_n &  b_n & \cdots & a_n + b_n\end{vmatrix} $$
My attempt was to substitute column 1 with column 1 - column 2 $(C_1 \to C_1 - C_2)$. Then do the same with others columns: $C_2 \to C_2 - C_3$,..., $C_n\to C_n - C_1$. After all these transformations, arise this determinant
$$ \alpha_n =\begin{vmatrix} 
a_1   &0& 0 &0&\cdots & -a_1 \\  
-a_2 &a_2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 &  -a_3 & a_3  & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & \cdots & a_n \end{vmatrix}  $$
So it seems that $\alpha_n$ only depends on $a_i$. However, computing the case $n=2$, gives
$$ \alpha_2 = \begin{vmatrix} 
a_1 +b_1  &b_1 \\ b_2 & a_2 + b_2 \end{vmatrix} = a_1a_2 + a_1b_2 + a_2b_1. $$
**What am I doing wrong?** How can I compute a closed form for $\alpha_n$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The last operation on $C_n$ doesn't seem correct, as  $C_1$ has been modified before.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your error was already clarified in other answers here only a hint to solution will be given.

I will assume $a_i\ne0$. Observe that your matrix is in form:
$$
\alpha=A+u^Tv,
$$
where
$$A=\operatorname {diag}(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n),\quad u=(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n),\quad
v=(1,1,\dots,1).
$$
Then by [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma):
$$
\det (\alpha)=(1+vA^{-1}u^T)\det (A)=\left(1+\sum_i\frac {b_i }{a_i}\right)\prod_i a_i.
$$

Comment: This answers my 2nd question in a very nice way. Thank you! +1

Comment: In fact the final expression written as $a_1a_2\dots a_{i-1}b_ia_{i+1}\dots a_n$ is valid also for the case of single $a_i$ equal to $0$. If there are more than one $a_i$ equal to $0$ the determinant is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that while performing row or column operations on determinants, it is necessary to preserve atleast one column/row, we cannot change all of them at once.

In your case, you cannot do $C_n \to C_n-C_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!